# How to find Maven plugin configuration parameters?

Tags: maven

I am looking for a systematic approach to find plugin configuration parameters in maven.

As each plugin in Maven defines its own configuration parameters, I was wondering if there is any "javadoc-style" standard catalog listing plugins along with their configuration parameters and some documentation ?

For example, in the following configuration, what would be the best approach to know how to configure this plugin, i.e how could you know the parameters "lifecycleMappingMetadata", "pluginExecutions"... and the values they accept :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
<artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<configuration>
    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
        <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.2.1,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                </action>
            </pluginExecution>
        </pluginExecutions>
    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Just visit the home page of the appropriate plugins for example for the exec-maven-plugin: See https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/ The link `goals` shows the list of goals which exist and same basic information about the plugin and minimum required java version..and a link to each goal will go to a page which shows all parameters with it's values...

Comment: For the m2e plugin which is only for the mapping in Eclipse (m2e) there exists also a complete documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

Comment: I find it always tricky to find the page containing the configuration parameters from the plugin homepage.

Comment: For all apache plugins you can find them under  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ for all plugins which have sites generated by Maven the structure is the same....

Comment: The key to finding the config parameters is, as mentioned by khmarbaise, to go to the `goals` page for the plugin, and opening the page of the goal you want to run. There you will find all parameters.